# Не могу создать проект с тестами Google Tests

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, google-test

Почему нет возможности создать проект Google Test в Visual Studio Community 2017? В инсталлере установлен адаптер тестов для Google Tests.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, что шаблон отсутствует. Однако он на самом деле малополезен, создавайте обычный проект пустого консольного приложения.

Comment: Оно там ректальным способом организовано. Проект тестирования от vcpckg зависит, чтобы GoogleTest разворачивался в солюшене как пакет.